Find a Cartesian Equation relating $x$ and $y$
I'm asked to find a Cartesian equation relating $x$ and $y$ to the parametric equations:
$x=\dfrac{5t}{1+t^3}$ and $y=\dfrac{9t^2}{1+t^3}$.
I tried to solve for one of the variables but ended up with $xt^3-5t+x=0$ and $yt^3-9t^2+y=0$. I'm unsure where to go from here and how to get my answer into the form of $P(x,y)=0$ where $P(x,y)$ is a polynomial in $x$ and $y$ such that the coefficient pf $x^3$ is $729$.

Try using $\frac yx=\frac95t$

Please use mathjax to edit your post.

You can note that
$$
x = \frac{5t}{1+t^3} = \frac{9t^2}{1+t^3} \cdot \frac 59 \cdot \frac 1t = \frac{5y}{9t}
$$
hence, $t = \frac{5y}{9x}$, and, substituting in one of parametric equations, you get for instance that
$$
x = \frac{5\cdot \frac{5y}{9x}}{1+\left(\frac{5y}{9x}\right)^3},
$$
whixh is the corresponding cartesian equation.

Observe carefully :
$$x=\frac{5t}{1+t^{3}}\tag{i}$$ and $$y=\frac{9t^{2}}{1+t^{3}}.\tag{ii}$$
From the $2^{\text{nd}}$ equation you can say that $$(1+t^{3})=\frac{9t^{2}}{y}.$$
Again $$x=\frac{5t}{1+t^{3}}.$$
Now, you know that $$(1+t^{3})=\frac{9t^{2}}{y}.$$
Therefore $$\frac{9t^{2}}{y}x=5t$$
$$\implies x=\frac{5y}{9t}$$
$$\implies t=\frac{5y}{9x}.$$
My solution is also similar to the other one but I tried to solve it by comparing $(1+t^{3})$ with the given $2$ equations.

The cartesian equation cannot include the variable $t$.

Yes I know that. But I just gave some hints to OP

If you are giving a hint, you should mention that in your post, instead of saying that "my solution is (...)".

Dividing
$$ \frac{y}{x}=\frac{9t}{5}; t=\frac{5y}{9x}; $$
Plug into given equation for x
$$ x = \dfrac{5t}{1+t^3}= \frac{25y}{9x}. \frac{9^3 x^3}{9^3 x^3+5^3y^3}$$
Simplifying
$$ xy= \frac{9x^3}{25}+ \frac{5y^3}{81}$$
The plot of the cubic curve has one self-intersection at origin $(0,0),$ is tangential to coordinate axes and has an asymptote of slope $-\dfrac{9}{5}.$

Observe that
$$9^3x^3+5^3y^3=9^35^3\frac{t^3}{(1+t^3)}\tag1$$
and
$$xy=9\cdot5\frac{t^3}{(1+t^3)}\tag2.$$
Hence,
$$9^3x^3+5^3y^3=9^25^2xy.$$
